# Delete specific data from Active android

Tags: java, activeandroid

Hey guys I am new in android development.
I got a problem in deleting the specific data from the active android.

edited *
from sugar to active android
thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of help do you expect with the information provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are talking about Active android. If yes then here is the solution for your problem.
You can make a class that represent table's data by extending **Model**.

Lets say you have a Class named as
 **AQIData** that extends **Model**

And lets say you have a attributes named **location_params** in it which represent **column name** of the table.You can delete the table data using **where** clause like below. 
Just make create a static method named **clearData()** and let this method ask for argument by which you can delete the specific data matching with the argument.

```
 public static void clearData(String location_params) {
        new Delete().from(AQIData.class).where("location_params =?", location_params).execute();
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: why down vote I am new in active android and android app development too. so please you have to consider with this

Comment: If you think this helped you .please accept it as a correct answer.